# Selectpicker doesn't show inside a table column

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table of movies and I am using ng-repeat to display the rows. But each column shows the movie variable (like name, director, actor, year..) and one of then is the genre but the movie can have multiple genres. So, I am using a select to do this.

The problem is, my select just don't show up in the screen! I don't know if this is a angular problem or I am doing something wrong..

Here is my table:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px; min-width: 90%" ng-controller="adminController">
<table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <h2>Filme</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2>Ano</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2>Diretor</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2>Ator/Atriz</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2>Pontuação</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2>Generos</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                &nbsp;
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="novoFilme.nome" placeholder="Nome do filme"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="novoFilme.ano" placeholder="Ano do filme"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="novoFilme.diretor" placeholder="Diretor do filme"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="novoFilme.ator" placeholder="Ator/atriz do filme"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="novoFilme.pontuacao" placeholder="Pontuação do filme"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="selectpicker" title="Nenhum selecionado" ng-model="novoFilme.generos" ng-options="genero.value as genero.nome for genero in generos" multiple>

                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addFilme()">Adicionar Filme</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="filme in filmes">
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="filme.nome"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="filme.ano"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="filme.diretor"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="filme.ator"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="filme.pontuacao"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="selectpicker" title="Nenhum selecionado" ng-options="genero.value as genero.nome for genero in generos" multiple>

                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right"><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(filme._id)">Remover</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('adminController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.generos = [
        {
            nome: "Comédia",
            value: "Comédia"
        },
        {
            nome: "Comédia Romântica",
            value: "Comédia Romântica"
        },
        {
            nome: "Drama",
            value: "Drama"
        },
        {
            nome: "Ação",
            value: "Ação"
        },
        {
            nome: "Policial",
            value: "Policial"
        },
        {
            nome: "Suspense",
            value: "Suspense"
        },
        {
            nome: "Terror",
            value: "Terror"
        }
    ];

    var atualizar = function () {
        $http.get('/filmes').success(function (response) {
            $scope.filmes = response;
            $scope.novoFilme = "";
        });
    };

    atualizar();

    $scope.addFilme = function () {
        $http.post('/filmes', $scope.novoFilme).success(function (response) {
            atualizar();
        });
    };

    $scope.remove = function (id) {
        $http.delete('/filmes/' + id).success(function (response) {
            atualizar();
        });
    };

    $scope.save = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.filmes.length; i++) {
            $http.put('/filmes/' + $scope.filmes[i]._id, $scope.filmes[i]).success(function (response) {
                atualizar();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Anyone knows how to fix it or any ideas how to do this in a different way?

Edit:
Here is the screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/duAkJ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem is just the select class, in this case `class="selectpicker"`, I don't know why this is causing issue, but if you remove this class will work fine.

Just to know, this class is a class from Silvio Moreto bootstrap select that you can find in the link below.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 0):

Well, [**`ngOptions`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) **requires** `ngModel` directive, so you have to use it in your `<select>` tag.

If you look at your console (pressing F12) you'll see this error:

> Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngOptions', can't be
>   found!

So, **Instead of:**

```
<select class="selectpicker" title="Nenhum selecionado" 
  ng-options="genero.value as genero.nome for genero in generos" multiple>
```

**Use:**

```
<select ng-model="genero" class="selectpicker" title="Nenhum selecionado" 
   ng-options="genero.value as genero.nome for genero in generos" multiple>
```

**Tip:** Always look at your console (F12) to see the errors when something went wrong.

Comment: Well, I added the ng-model="filme.generos" because I want that to be my movie genres, but still don't working and actually there is nothing in my console.

Comment: Strange.. it works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/caxeIyXtlSVoWbNdSXWE?p=preview Also you can remove this "title" property.. If you want to set a default value do what I did in my plnkr.

Comment: But in your example the select isn't inside a ng-repeat, and I think that is the root of the problem but I am not sure.

Comment: Take a look again.. I put `ngRepeat` now.

Comment: Now I don't know.. Maybe it is the table but it doesn't make sense.. I can't find a example of a table with ng-repeat and a select in a column, so I am lost, I don't why this is happening.

Comment: No, the fact that is a table can just be discarded, even you can test my example with `<table>`. As a debug, put in your HTML this: `{{ generos }}`, see if the genres are ok.